# Json string written to Kafka using Spark is not converted properly on reading

Tags: json, csv, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I read a .csv file to create a data frame and I want to write the data to a kafka topic. The code is the following

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(f'{file_location}')
kafka_df = df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value").selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
kafka_df.show(truncate=False)
```

And the data frame looks like this:

```
value
"{""id"":""d215e9f1-4d0c-42da-8f65-1f4ae72077b3"",""latitude"":""-63.571457254062715"",""longitude"":""-155.7055842710919""}"
"{""id"":""ca3d75b3-86e3-438f-b74f-c690e875ba52"",""latitude"":""-53.36506636464281"",""longitude"":""30.069167069917597""}"
"{""id"":""29e66862-9248-4af7-9126-6880ceb3b45f"",""latitude"":""-23.767505281795835"",""longitude"":""174.593140405442""}"
"{""id"":""451a7e21-6d5e-42c3-85a8-13c740a058a9"",""latitude"":""13.02054867061598"",""longitude"":""20.328402498420786""}"
"{""id"":""09d6c11d-7aae-4d17-8cd8-183157794893"",""latitude"":""-81.48976715040848"",""longitude"":""1.1995769642056189""}"
"{""id"":""393e8760-ef40-482a-a039-d263af3379ba"",""latitude"":""-71.73949722379649"",""longitude"":""112.59922770487054""}"
"{""id"":""d6db8fcf-ee83-41cf-9ec2-5c2909c18534"",""latitude"":""-4.034680969008576"",""longitude"":""60.59645511854336""}"
```

After I wrote it to Kafka I want to read it and transform the binary data from column "value" back to json string but the result is that the value contains only the id, not the whole string. Any ideea why?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = consume_from_event_hub(topic, bootstrap_servers, config, consumer_group)
string_df = df.select(F.col("value").cast("string"))
string_df.display()
```

```
value
794541bc-30e6-4c16-9cd0-3c5c8995a3a4
20ea5b50-0baa-47e3-b921-f9a3ac8873e2
598d2fc1-c919-4498-9226-dd5749d92fc5
86cd5b2b-1c57-466a-a3c8-721811ab6959
807de968-c070-4b8b-86f6-00a865474c35
e708789c-e877-44b8-9504-86fd9a20ef91
9133a888-2e8d-4a5a-87ce-4a53e63b67fc
cd5e3e0d-8b02-45ee-8634-7e056d49bf3b
```

the CSV the format is this

```
id,latitude,longitude 
bd6d98e1-d1da-4f41-94ba-8dbd8c8fce42,-86.06318155350924,-108.14300138138589
c39e84c6-8d7b-4cc5-b925-68a5ea406d52,74.20752175171859,-129.9453606091319
011e5fb8-6ab7-4ee9-97bb-acafc2c71e15,19.302250885973592,-103.2154291337162
```

Comment: Are you sure the data has been written properly in Kafka? How do you write and read from Kafka? Can you read it with `kafkacat` or some other tool to check what it is exactly in the Kafka topic?

Comment: I wrote it to an event hub so I don't think so. The only thing that I'm doing is this ```kafka_df.write\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("topic", topic)\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers)\
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")\
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", config)\
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)\
    .save()
```

Comment: After you read the CSV, what is the schema of this df and can you send a print? It's seems you paste the csv file. It's not a clean JSON file as it contains duplicated double quotes. It's not clear how this file was parsed into a JSON

Comment: After I read the CSV the format is this ```id,latitude,longitude
bd6d98e1-d1da-4f41-94ba-8dbd8c8fce42,-86.06318155350924,-108.14300138138589
c39e84c6-8d7b-4cc5-b925-68a5ea406d52,74.20752175171859,-129.9453606091319
011e5fb8-6ab7-4ee9-97bb-acafc2c71e15,19.302250885973592,-103.2154291337162```

Comment: Also the double quotes appear after I cast the column "value" from json to string, the files was parsed using ```.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")` since `to_json` already returns a string column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_json, struct
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(f'{file_location}')
kafka_df = df.select(to_json(struct(col("*"))).alias("value"))
kafka_df.show(truncate=False)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the consumer. That should have worked unless `consume_from_event_hub` does something specifically to extract the ID column